# Laravel Nova get selected resources ids in action

Tags: laravel

I need to be able to access the selected resources ids within `handleRequest` method, without dealing with `handle` method

```
public function handleRequest(ActionRequest $request){
  
// here i need to handle ids

}
```

for example:
i've selected 350000 resources which is large number of records, i just need to know the ids of those resources so i can handle it in queue or background job.

**my question: how can i get the ids without actual instances just selected ids?**

Answer (score 0):

```php
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        $models->pluck('id')->all(); // get the id's of all models
    }
```

Comment: Please add some context and explanation for future readers.